# MySQL Loop in Union and select *

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using redash for mySQL data source and trying to create a dashboard.
I have many table with the name as **tablename_2021_01_01, tablename_2021_01_02, tablename_2021_01_03, tablename_2021_01_04** and so on. All these tables contain data in the same format. Now i want to pull data from 30 tables in one shot. How to do it?

Comment: Look up the UNION syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, today you learned that the "Table-per-Day" model for storing your data is a Bad Idea.
Generally speaking, "Table-per-*anything*" is a poor choice these days.
With proper indexing, there is absolutely *no reason* why all of this data couldn't live in just *one* table.

Also, I'm pretty sure MySQL still has the *hard limit* for the number of tables in a query (including those in any Views used) of [just] **61** tables, which is only *double* what you're currently asking for.

As to your *immediate* question, "**union all**" is your friend.

```
select * from tablename_2021_01_01
union all 
select * from tablename_2021_01_02
union all 
select * from tablename_2021_01_03
. . . 
where ...
```